# PHP .htaccess Rewrite - Pretty URLs in localhost

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a PHP script over my localhost, and I have this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Domain

#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1 [L]
```

This code allows me to access this URL

```
http://localhost/Domain/index.php?mode=overview
```

as

```
http://localhost/Domain/overview
```

But I want to access this URL

```
http://localhost/Domain/index.php?mode=overview&s=10
```

as

```
http://localhost/Domain/overview/10
```

and I failed to get it :(

Please anyone can help me out on this !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Domain/

#Make sure it's an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
#Make sure its a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]

#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I still have the same problem, this line "RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1 [L,QSA]" works fine.

But this line "RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]" not working.

Comment: Did you copy/paste this code as is or you have modified it?

Comment: No but webpage without any styles

Comment: I copy and paste it as it :(

Comment: First of all `webpage without any styles` means rule **worked** since you didn't get 404.

Comment: For css/js path issues just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/Domain/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: AWESOME ! Thank you for information about BASE tag, Finally works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Replacing the last line of your .htaccess file with this code should do the trick.

```
^/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1&s=$2
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.  If it does work, this is why:

It's looking for a word after the base url, in your case `http://localhost/Domain/`
is the base url.  This match "^(.*)" is captured in buffer 1, referenced as "$1".  Then it wants a forward slash, followed by another capture word at the end of the url, "(.*)$".  This match is in capture buffer 2, "$2".  If this match is found it is then rewrote to index.php with appropriate capture buffers.

Comment: I just edited it, now try it with both forward slashes as shown if you have not already.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the issue is and am unable to test right now.  A variant of what you have should work, maybe with `^/?(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?mode=$1&s=$2 [NC, L]`.

Comment: If that does not work, could always use a more restricted expression such as `^/?([a-z]+)/(.*)/?$ index.php?mode=$1&s=$2 [NC, L]`

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions before I posted my problem here but no one worked for me. Your last solution returned "Internal Server Error" and when remove NC, I get webpage without any styles.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
RewriteRule ^overview/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?mode=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand how rewriting and/or regular expressions work. This would take whatever comes after `overview/` and append it after `mode=`. That's definitely not what the OP wants. Not only are you making `overview` fixed/static/required, but you're putting the wrong thing after `mode=` and ignoring the `s=` part.